# Self compressing/decompressing program

Tags: code-golf, compression

#### Challenge:

Write a lossless encoder/decoder that is able to compress its own source code.

#### Usage:

`progname` **`encode`**

Encodes data provided on the standard input, writes the encoded representation of the data to the standard output.

`progname` **`decode`**

Decodes data produced by `progname` **`encode`**. Reads the encoded data from the standard input, writes the decoded data to standard output. Must perfectly restore the original data.

#### Example:

```
$ progname encode < /usr/include/stdlib.h > encoded
$ progname decode < encoded > decoded
$ diff -qs /usr/include/stdlib.h decoded
Files /usr/include/stdlib.h and decoded are identical
```

#### Requirements:

1. It must be a real lossless encoder/decoder for *all* inputs - encoding any data and then decoding it must produce the original data.
2. If the input is identical to the program's source code, the size of encoded output must be less than the size of the input.

#### Score:

Size of the program's source code + the size of its encoded source code

#### Clarification:

The program doesn't need to be a general purpose compressor/decompressor. That's why its commands are called encode/decode. It may also use existing tools predating this question.

Comment: The problem I see is that it doesn't necessarily have to be *good* compression. You could simply map the program input to a single byte and all other inputs to themselves, and get a crazy good score. Basically like [lenpeg](http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/lenpeg.html) but recognizing it's own source code instead

Comment: @DrMcMoylex That's OK. I intentionally didn't add restrictions preventing such an implementation.

Comment: It has been put on hold while I was writing my answer. I think this is a perfectly valid and interesting challenge.

Comment: NodeJS, 330 bytes: `b=";c=require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin','ascii');p=process.argv[2][0];s='b='+JSON.stringify(b)+b;process.stdout.write(p=='e'?((c==s)?'':'0'+c):(c?c.slice(1):s))";c=require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin','ascii');p=process.argv[2][0];s='b='+JSON.stringify(b)+b;process.stdout.write(p=='e'?((c==s)?'':'0'+c):(c?c.slice(1):s))`